# React devtools does not have a profiler tab in electron

Tags: electron, react-devtools

When I open React devtools in electron, it works, but it has no [`Profiler`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) tab.

I have updated the extension, as far as I can tell, using `electron-devtools-installer` but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

I'm using `react 16.5.0` and `react-dom 16.6.3`

Comment: The doc says that profiling is only available in development mode. Is this the case for you? (Just checking)

Comment: I believe so; I'm away from this, but I'm 90% sure it's in development mode